# Prove the principality of pseudoprimes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $a^2 -1$ is nor divisible by prime $p$, then $M$ is Fermat pseudo prime, where $M = ab$ and $a = (a^p -1)/(a-1)$ and $b = (a^p + 1)/(a+1)$....$(1)$

What I have did so far:

Here $M$= $(a^{2p} -1)$/$(a^2 -1)$. I subtracted $1$ for both sides, I got:

$M-1$= $(a^{2p} -a^2)$/$(a^2$-1)....(*)

by Fermat little theorem says $a^{2p} -a^2$ is divisible by $p$

From (*), since $a^2-1$ is not divisible by $p$ and $a^{2p} -a^2$ divisible by $p$; One can realize that $M-1$ is divisible by $p$.

Now my question is how to prove that $p|M-1$?
Or $M-1 = pk$ for some $k.$
Or $M= pk+1$

if $M= pk+1$ is true, how to prove $pk+1$ is divisible by two different primes being $M$ is pseudo prime?

Please answer.

---

If I am wrong, Please prove my statement $(1)$ in any other method. Please...

Comment: @please answer or prove in some other way. Or suggest me where I am wrong?